# Extract name from email using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string - which is chain of emails, i needed to extract the name of the sender `(From :)`. Find below a sample of email

```
str1 <- 'From : Wendy YEOW (SLA) To : xxxx@lt.org Subject : RE: OneService@S
From: SLA Enquiry (SLA) Sent: Friday, 5 June, 2015 5:26 PM To : xxxx@lt.org Subject : RE: OneService@S 
From: Siti Zaharah RAMAN (ARKS) Sent: Friday, 5 June, 2015 5:26 PM To : xxxx@lt.org Subject : RE: OneService@S 
From: SLA Enquiry (SLA) Sent: Friday, 5 June, 2015 5:26 PM To : xxxx@lt.org Subject : RE: OneService@S 
From: Chin Hwang LAU (TA) Sent: Friday, 5 June, 2015 5:26 PM To : xxxx@lt.org Subject : RE: OneService@S'
```

I have the below code - to extract the names

```
str_extract_all(string=str1,pattern="\\b(From\\s*[:]+\\s*(\\w*))\\b")[[1]]
[1] "From : Wendy" "From: SLA"    "From: Siti"   "From: SLA"    "From: Chin"
```

But my desired output is:

```
[1] "Wendy YEOW (SLA)"    "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"    "Siti Zaharah RAMAN (ARKS)"   "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"    "Chin Hwang LAU (TA)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strsplit`. There's no need for `gsub` here.

```
strsplit(str1, "From ?: | (To|Sent) ?:.*?(\\nFrom ?: |$)")[[1]][-1]
# [1] "Wendy YEOW (SLA)"          "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"         "Siti Zaharah RAMAN (ARKS)"
# [4] "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"         "Chin Hwang LAU (TA)"
```

The regex basically consists of two parts:

1. `"From ?: "`: This ist the beginning of the string. The split returns an empty string and the rest of the original string.
2. `" (To|Sent) ?:.*?(\\nFrom ?: |$)"`: This regex represents the text after the name. It includes the substring starting with `"To"` or `"Sent"` and ending with a line break (`"\\n"`) followed by the next `"From"` or the end of the string (`"$"`).

Finally, the `[-1]` is necessary to remove the empty string (preceding the first `"From"`).

Comment: This is neat and I'd like to understand why this even works. Can you please add some commentary?

Comment: @Andrie I added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll go and re-read how `strsplit` deals with the regex. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression together with `strsplit()`:

```
gsub("From *: (.*?) (To|Sent).*", "\\1", strsplit(str1, "\n")[[1]])

[1] "Wendy YEOW (SLA)"         
[2] "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"        
[3] "Siti Zaharah RAMAN (ARKS)"
[4] "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"        
[5] "Chin Hwang LAU (TA)"
```

This works because I am using a back reference (`\\1`) to extract the wildcard in the first set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Not much elegant, but you can try:

```
gsub(" *(From|To|Sent) *:? *","",regmatches(str1,gregexpr("From *:[^:]+",str1))[[1]])
#[1] "Wendy YEOW (SLA)"          "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"        
#[3] "Siti Zaharah RAMAN (ARKS)" "SLA Enquiry (SLA)"        
#[5] "Chin Hwang LAU (TA)"
```

Comment: If name is somthing like `From : Tony Kwa / Ke DY` - the above code reulsts in `ny Kwa / Ke DY` . It removes the To word from the actual name –